# Can I use another pin instead of VIN?

Tags: amplifier, audio, esp32

I'm currently trying to copy a setup (seen below) for an audio player using an ESP32-S2-Saola-1 instead of an ESP32-Wroom.

The problem is that the ESP32-S2-Saola-1 doesn't have a VIN pin. Can I use another pin instead of VIN or is it simply not needed?

I'm powering the board with USB and using a PAM8403 as my amplifier.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pinout of the modules isn't enough to answer this question.  You need the [schematic diagram of the ESP32-S2-Saola-1](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/ESP32-S2-SAOLA-1_V1.1_schematics.pdf) to see if it can be made to work.

The sketch you are working from shows the amplifier drawing power from the VIN pin of the WROOM32.  The VIN pin of the WROOM32 therefore must deliver 5V to the amplifier.

The ESP32-S2-Saola-1 schematic shows that the USB 5V (marked "VBUS" in the schematic) goes to the module +5V line through a diode:

[image]

The green line shows you how VBUS connects to +5V.

The blue circles show that the +5V line connects to pin 20 of J2.  That's the pin marked "5V0" in the ESP32-S2-Saola-1 pinout that you posted in the question.

That answers your question:  5V0 is a 5V output that you can use to power your amplifier.

5V0 is also a 5V input to the ESP32-S2-Saola-1.  If you don't have USB power, you can connect a 5V power supply to that pin and power the ESP32-S2-Saola-1.

---

The [PAM8403](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/PAM8403-247318.pdf) is a 3 watt amplifier.

You will have to make sure that your USB source can provide at least 600 milliamperes of current so that the amplifier can reach its full output power.

The [1N5819HW-7-F](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0011683586_1-2543674.pdf)  diode between VBUS and 5V0 on the ESP32-S2-Saola-1 is rated for 1 ampere average current with peaks up to 1.5 ampere.  You should be able to get enough current for the PAM8403 through the 5V0 pin without damaging the diode.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to power the amp board from ESP board. It is needed. Your board has 5V pin.

Answer (score 0):

First are you sure that this connection is correct in the picture? VIN is for external power to use for the ESP board and not to provide power to the amplifier.

Anyway, if you power the ESP board from USB then you have only to provide power to the amplifier.

You connect GND with GND and VCC of the amplifier with 3.3V or 5V (depends on the specification of the board) and also the audio input to the ESP.

Comment: Please add some schematic clues to make the answer more readable.